# How do you update the server name in source indexed symbol file?

Tags: tfs, srcsrv

With the Debugging Tools for Windows you can run SSIndex.cmd against your symbol files and it will embed the command to retrieve each source code file from the TF server.  We have a bunch of indexed files and recently our IT migrated our TFS 2008 installation to TFS 2010 and in the process changed the server name.  Question is, how can I update all these symbol files to point to the new server?  I thought SSindex used an alternate data stream named 'srcsrv' but SysInternals' streams.exe shows nothing on these symbol files even though srctool.exe shows the data.

Comment: So I tried modifying the PDB file to change the text but VS doesn't recognize the new binary as a matching PDB.  Doh!

Comment: You could always setup a CNAME on your DNS server to get the old name to resolve to the new server.

Comment: The old server URL was was something like http://server:8080/ and the new one is like http://newserver:8080/tfs/bar.  Would a CNAME still work in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I emailed the WinDbg team at Microsoft and got the answer which is to define the SERVER variable in a srcsrv.ini file that goes into the Common7\IDE dir of Visual Studio (if you use VS for debugging).

```
[variables]
FOOSERVER=http://servername.acme.com:8080/tfs/FOO/
```

Where the FOO of FOOSERVER corresponds to your TFS team project name.

Comment: This does not work.  Has the path changed since this post?